# Rreport/LaTeX quality output package

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I'm looking for some LaTeX template for creating quality output. On R-bloggers I've bumped on Frank Harrel's Rreport package. Due to my quite modest LaTeX abilities, only a user-friendly (and noob-friendly) interface should suffice. Here's a [link](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/Rreport) to an official website. I'm following the instructions, but I cannot manage to install an app. I use Ubuntu 9.10, R version is 2.10.1 (updated regularly from UCLA's CRAN server), and of course, cvs is installed on my system.

Now, I'd like to know if there is some user-friendly LaTeX template package (Sweave is still to advanced/spartan for me). I'm aware that my question is quite confounding, but a brief glance on examples on Rreport page should give you a hint. I'm aware that LaTeX skills are a must, but just for now I need something that will suit my needs (as a psychological researcher).

Is there any package similar with Rreport?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to create a LaTeX report without writing any LaTeX?

Comment: What do you mean with "pandan"?

Comment: Sorry for that... It was kind of sleepy Serbian-to-English translation! I've corrected it!
Pandan = equivalent, alternative, similar to, alike...

Comment: @Shane, I'm looking for some easy-to-use report tool, and hopefully I'll dig LaTeX syntax by the way... I don't want to be swarmed with complex LaTeX syntax right from the start!
Anyway, anyone managed to install Rreport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lyx? http://www.lyx.org/

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install lyx
```

From the lyx page:

> LyX combines the power and flexibility
>   of TeX/LaTeX with the ease of use of a
>   graphical interface. This results in
>   world-class support for creation of
>   mathematical content (via a fully
>   integrated equation editor) and
>   structured documents like academic
>   articles, theses, and books.

Comment: Thanks for this one! Tex is great, but I need something more Sweave-like: define input parameters, and the function returns an output (something like this:  http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/Rreport/report.pdf)

Comment: You can use Sweave with Lyx (http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2008-1.pdf). It seems the Rreport only produces documents with the same structure? If you only need one report format with different data, perhaps the easiest solution is to ask someone to create the template for you in LaTex+Sweave.

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out this feature. I've been successfully avoiding LaTeX, but now it looks like "the avoidance period" finally came to an end. Learning LaTeX is painstaking, but effort pays off in the end. So, as far as I can tell, you solved this one for me! Thanks again! =)

Comment: ... and a little reference (how-to for Linux): http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyxWithRThroughSweave

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce Latex with a simpler markup you could use the ASCII package that has a Sweave driver that can be used with reSTructured text, which can then be converted to Latex.  Although I would only use it if you want to be able to convert the same doc also to html or odf. In any case it is a good idea to learn the basic Latex.

Answer (score 1):

The online text processor [zoho](http://www.zoho.com) allows export to latex. Maybe this can be helpful to learn latex, but I do not know how to integrate Sweave/R in this. (I did not work with zoho, by the way).