# converting a multidimensional ctab()-table to LaTeX format

Tags: r, latex

I am using `ctab()` from the `catspec` package to generate a 3-way table. But is there any way to format the output latex-ready? This would seem like a very simple thing to do:

```
library(catspec)
ctab(Titanic)

                   Survived  No Yes
Class Sex    Age                   
1st   Male   Child            0   5
             Adult          118  57
      Female Child            0   1
             Adult            4 140
2nd   Male   Child            0  11
             Adult          154  14
      Female Child            0  13
             Adult           13  80
3rd   Male   Child           35  13
             Adult          387  75
      Female Child           17  14
             Adult           89  76
Crew  Male   Child            0   0
             Adult          670 192
      Female Child            0   0
             Adult            3  20
```

But then what?

Comment: The [tables](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/index.html) package does this sort of formatting, I believe, but the special syntax to get there might be a barrier.

Comment: there's also [a convenient function](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/01/printing-nested-tables-in-r-bridging-between-the-reshape-and-tables-packages/) to translate from reshape to tabular.

Comment: I don't see why this is off-topic. -- Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6892758/946850)?

Comment: What is off-topic? In any case, cheers for the pointers, @baptiste. Takes a moment to get into `tables`, but then it's quite powerful!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste) for the [pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759700/converting-a-multidimensional-ctab-table-to-latex-format/16759912?noredirect=1#comment24179725_16759700) to the [`tables` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/index.html). Have a look at the very detailed [`tables` vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) with lots of nice examples and a systematic explanation of terms. And here is how this will make your example work (without using `ctab()`, though):

```
df <- as.data.frame.table(Titanic)

require('tables')
latex(tabular(RowFactor(Class, spacing=1) * RowFactor(Sex, spacing=1) * Factor(Age) ~ Freq * Heading() * identity * Survived, data = df ))
```

It is true that getting your head around how these formulas work takes a moment (and some trial and error...), but the examples in the vignette help a lot and the package is a damn flexible tool!

More info on generating latex tables in R is provided here:
[Tools for making latex tables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r)

Comment: Nope. Entirely silent on ctab().

Comment: Well, I guess you'll have to find a way to make it work with one of the packages. E.g. have a look at the `xtable` package, it provides an interface to create latex tables from the formats printed by `methods(xtable).`To reformat your data, the `reshape2` package might help.

Comment: xtable can handle 2 dimensions max.

Comment: Yep, I realise that now. Which is why I also upvoted your question, because it is very interesting and I couldn't come up with any solution by having a quick look into it. Currently I have no time to look into more detail, but will see if I find more time the next days!

Comment: Thanks in advance. One would think this would be an easy thing to do.

Comment: Yep, that was my initial though when posting the answer!

Comment: Edited my answer to include a little workaround to make your data structure work with xtable. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hiya! I edited my answer again, making use of baptiste's advice to work with the `tables` package. This is quite flexible in layouting tables and can also format them for LaTeX! Does this do the trick for you?