# Getting standard errors for lme4 object with texreg

Tags: r, lme4, texreg

I've been using the fantastic package texreg to produce high-quality HTML tables from lme4 models.  Unfortunately, by default, texreg creates confidence intervals, rather than standard errors, under the coefficients for models from lme4 (see page 17 of the [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v55/i08/paper)).

As an example:

```
library(lme4)
library(texreg)
screenreg(lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy))
```

produces

```
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
Computing confidence intervals at a confidence level of 0.95. Use argument "method = 'boot'" for bootstrapped CIs.

===============================================
                               Model 1         
-----------------------------------------------
(Intercept)                     251.41 *       
                               [237.68; 265.13]
Days                             10.47 *       
                               [  7.36;  13.58]
-----------------------------------------------
AIC                            1755.63         
BIC                            1774.79         
Log Likelihood                 -871.81         
Deviance                       1743.63         
Num. obs.                       180            
Num. groups: Subject             18            
Variance: Subject.(Intercept)   612.09         
Variance: Subject.Days           35.07         
Variance: Residual              654.94         
===============================================
* 0 outside the confidence interval
```

And I would prefer to see something like this:

```
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
Computing confidence intervals at a confidence level of 0.95. Use argument "method = 'boot'" for bootstrapped CIs.

===============================================
                               Model 1         
-----------------------------------------------
(Intercept)                     251.41 *       
                                (24.74)
Days                             10.47 *       
                                 (5.92)
-----------------------------------------------
[output truncated for clarity]
```

Is there a way to over-ride this behavior?  Using the ci.force = FALSE option doesn't work, as far as I can tell.

I'm sticking with texreg, rather than [one of the other packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r) like stargazer, because texreg allows me to group coefficients into meaningful groups.

Thanks in advance for your help!

(UPDATE: edited to include an example)

Comment: Please consider including a *small* [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can better understand and more easily answer your question.

Comment: Thanks!  I put one in.  Hopefully that helps to clarify.  If not please let me know.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `naive=TRUE` gets close to what you want ...

```
library(lme4); library(texreg)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
screenreg(fm1,naive=TRUE)

## ==========================================
##                                Model 1    
## ------------------------------------------
## (Intercept)                     251.41 ***
##                                  (6.82)   
## Days                             10.47 ***
##                                  (1.55)   
## ------------------------------------------
## [etc.]
```

I don't know where you got your values of 24.94, 5.92 from ... ?

```
sqrt(diag(vcov(fm1)))
## [1] 6.824556 1.545789

cc <- confint(fm1,which="beta_")
apply(cc,1,diff)/3.84
## (Intercept)        Days 
##    7.14813     1.61908
```

The implied standard errors based on scaling the profile confidence intervals are a little bit wider, but not hugely different.

What I don't know how to do easily is to get significance tests/stars based on profile confidence intervals while still getting standard errors in the table. According to the `ci.test` entry in `?texreg`,

- when CIs are printed, `texreg` prints a *single* star if the confidence intervals don't include zero
- when SEs are printed it prints the standard number of stars based on the size of the p-value

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  I got the SEs from `summary(fm1)` but clearly that gave me something other than what I thought.  The star behavior using the naive = T option was what I wanted; I wanted stars based on the size of the p-value, not based on whether the CI included 0.

Comment: FWIW you copied the standard deviations of the random effects from the summary, not the standard errors of the fixed-effect parameters ...

Answer (score 2):

You can also try setting the 'include.ci' parameter to FALSE

```
model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
texreg(model, include.ci = FALSE)
```