# R: Creating Latex tables without environment code

Tags: r, latex

How can I print latex-formatted tables (e.g. summary statistics, no regression output) in R, but without the environment code like `\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering`?

I tried many packages listed in [Tools for making latex tables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r). Only the stargazer package seems to have an option for suppressing Latex environment code, namely `out.header=FALSE`. But that option seems to have no effect. Other packages seem to haven even less options.

Background: I have two table of very similar kind (spearman and pearson correlation, in my very case) which I would like to have in one table in Latex. I think of simply calling the R generated, latex-formatted output in a third latex file, which is ultimately called in the Latex document.
But if there are other possibilities to create two R generated Latex-style tables in one `.tex` document, I'd be glad to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with **xtable**:

Here's default behavior:

```
> print(xtable(table(1:5)))
% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Sat Nov 08 14:57:56 2014
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & V1 \\ 
  \hline
1 &   1 \\ 
  2 &   1 \\ 
  3 &   1 \\ 
  4 &   1 \\ 
  5 &   1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

If you include `floating = FALSE` in the `print` method options, you can get your desired result:

```
> print(xtable(table(1:5)), floating = FALSE)
% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Sat Nov 08 14:57:51 2014
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & V1 \\ 
  \hline
1 &   1 \\ 
  2 &   1 \\ 
  3 &   1 \\ 
  4 &   1 \\ 
  5 &   1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

There's very fine-grained control here, but  most of the options are described in `? print.xtable`, not `? xtable`.

Comment: Now that I know the right option I realize that stargazer offers it too: `stargazer(..., float=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you merge the two tables into one data.frame in a first step, and then format the combined thing for your task? There are only few details in your question but I imagine something along these lines here could work:

```
x <- rbind( cor(mtcars, use="complete.obs", method="spearman"),
            cor(mtcars, use="complete.obs", method="pearson" ))
rownames( x )[12:22] <- paste( rownames( x )[12:22], "a", sep = "-" )
xLatex <- xtable( x )
```

Comment: Because I want to include a sub-headline (Panel A, Panel B). Additionally, the solution you posted relies on the definition of the rownames, which is relatively hard to generalize.

Comment: Some more details about the tables you want to combine would be helpful.