# How to un-flat a dataframe/table in R for a presentation in HTML or LaTeX?

Tags: r

I have an aggregated data frame after use of melt/dcast functions:

```
    Agency     potential_danger_x     potential_danger_y     danger_x     danger_y
    A                  165                    12.232            23          23.98
    B                   34                    43.98             12          12.43
```

Since I must create a presentation, I just cannot present the dataframe like this (sigh!). I've tried to find a way to get an HTML or TeX presentation like this:

```
                             potential danger                        danger
    Agency              x                       y                x            y
    A                  165                    12.232            23          23.98
    B                   34                    43.98             12          12.43
```

but I found no way. I don't expect that you do the work for me but I would greatly appreciate a little guidance about how to manage this issue or which package could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use package stargazer:

```
install.package(stargazer)
require(stargazer)
stargazer(attitude, summary = FALSE)
```

The summary = FALSE, will present the data as is. The output is TeX, then you retype the headers, or insert another row.

Comment: Thank you @Repmat, unfortunately, it seems that there is no package that do all the work but your help was useful.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to have a look at this page: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r) which gives an overview of some other R packages which are useful for formating tables.

I personally like the `xtable` package.