# R output to look like text table

Tags: r, formatting

I want to create an R output to look like a text table.

My dataframe is this:

```
  header1 header2                         header3
1  abcdef   horse today is going to be a good day
2     123    ball    yesterday was not a good day
```

But, I would like for the output to look like this:

```
+---------+---------+-------------------------+
| header1 | header2 |         header3         |
+---------+-----------------------------------+
|abcdef   |horse    |today is a great day     |
+---------+---------+-------------------------+
|123      |ball     |tomorrow is a greater day|
+---------+---------+-------------------------+
```

I feel like there is a function that can do this, but I am not able to find it.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-7.html

Comment: [Tools for making latex tables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r)

Comment: The ascii package is the one... Thanks for the quick response!