# creating frequency table in R

Tags: r, group-by, xtable

I have extracted some summary statistics from R:

```
group_by(starters, starters$Programme, starters$Gender ) %>%   summarise(
    count = n(),
    # mean = mean(Total_testscore, na.rm = TRUE),
    # sd = sd(Total_testscore, na.rm = TRUE),
    percentage = (n()/238)*100)

group_by(starters, starters$Programme ) %>%   summarise(
    count = n(),
    mean = mean(Total_testscore, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(Total_testscore, na.rm = TRUE),    percentage = (n()/238)*100)
```

and would like to get a table that looks like this :

[image]

I am using `xtables` to export my output to latex for all my other results. For `xtables` all my results have to be in one table. How can i combine the two outputs in order to get a table like pictured?

Comment: Not an answer but have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r)?

Comment: there are a number of packages with names like "tableone", "table1", etc, that might do what you need.

Comment: Have a look at `flextable` as well.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `$` within `group_by`, just use the bare column name