# Multi-row latex table with R

Tags: r, latex, character, tabular, multirow

I have this data frame :

```
mydf <- data.frame(rowFactor1 = c(rep("S4",6),rep("S5",6),rep("S6",6)),
                   rowFactor2 = rep(c("All","T1/T2(V)"), 9),
                   colFactor1 = rep(c(rep("Ml",2),rep("Mp",2),rep("Mra",2)), 3), 
                   x = c(
                     "8.73",
                     "0.46 / 8.28 ( 2 )",
                     "7.02",
                     "0.84 / 8.28 ( 3 )",
                     "0.55",
                     "0.90 / 1.20 ( 0 )",
                     "8.14",
                     "2.02 / 1.57 ( 5 )",
                     "0.55",
                     "2.90 / 1.28 ( 4 )",
                     "1.73",
                     "3.46 / 8.28 ( 6 )",
                     "6.02",
                     "0.87 / 8.90 ( 5 )",
                     "1.55",
                     "0.90 / 1.20 ( 1 )",
                     "6.24",
                     "2.02 / 1.57 ( 7 )"
                   ))
```

How to create a **Latex** table with multiple rows using `mydf` on R?

I tried to use the `tabular` function of the R package `tables`

```
tab1 <- tabular(Heading()*RowFactor(rowFactor1, spacing = 1, 
                                    c("S4","S5","S6"))*
                  Heading()*RowFactor(rowFactor2, 
                                      levelnames = c("All","T1/T2(V)")) ~ 
                  Heading()*Factor(colFactor1, 
                                   levelnames = c("Ml","Mp","Mra")),
                data = mydf)
latex(tab1)
```

I had this table without x's values (`8.73, 0.46 / 8.28 ( 2 )` ...) ​​and filled with a single value `1`.

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think you are looking for `library (tidyr) mydf %>%
 spread(colFactor1, x)`

Comment: @tmfmnk thank you for your suggestion but I need a Latex table using R.

Comment: @FloraGrappelli Please don't edit post to add thank you lines. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328380/2777074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use strings in the table, maybe convert your `x` factor to character:

```
mydf$x <- as.character(mydf$x)
```

Then include the `x` strings as follows:

```
library(tables)

tab1 <- tabular(Heading()*RowFactor(rowFactor1, spacing = 1, 
                                    c("S4","S5","S6"))*
                  Heading()*RowFactor(rowFactor2, 
                                      levelnames = c("All","T1/T2(V)")) ~ 
                  Heading()*Factor(colFactor1, 
                                   levelnames = c("Ml","Mp","Mra"))*
                  Heading()*(x)*Heading()*identity,
                  data = mydf)
latex(tab1)
```

Also consider alternatives to `tabular` for Latex tables:

[Tools for making latex tables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r)

[image: Latex table using tabular]