# In R, make a "pretty" result table in LaTeX, PDF, or HTML from "IRR" package output

Tags: r, latex, stargazer, texreg

**Background**

I'm using the `irr` package in `R` to generate some inter-rater reliability statistics for a project I'm doing. Here's an example of Fleiss's Kappa using the package's built-in data:

```
install.packages("irr")
library(irr)
data("diagnoses", package = "irr")
diagnoses2 <- diagnoses[, 1:3]
kappam.fleiss(diagnoses2)
```

This gives a simple little output table that looks like this in the R console:

[image]

**The Problem & Desired Result**

I'd like to "prettify" this output so that I can import it into a LaTeX document that I'm using to write up the results.

I'll take basically any format as long as its more or less automatic: LaTeX, a PDF or PNG image, even an HTML version of the table. The issue is that I have several of these output tables to make, and I'd rather not have to awkwardly convert them into LaTeX format manually. I'll do it if I have to, but I'd love to save the time.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried using `knitr` on this like so:

```
knitr::kable(diagnoses2, "latex")
```

But it doesn't work too well: `cannot coerce class ‘"irrlist"’ to a data.frame`.

I've looked at another 2 packages that've helped me in the past, `texreg` and `stargazer`, but their documentation doesn't say that they support `irr` outputs so I haven't actually tried them yet. (Though I will once I post this.) In the meantime, I'm also going through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r) to see if anything works. Thanks for your time.

**EDIT / ADDENDUM**

There are some neat answers below from @akrun and @TarJae, using novel (to me) methods and packages. These approaches may be of great help for statistical outputs from packages that aren't `irr` but that also aren't "officially supported" in packages like `texreg` or `stargazer`. I think they may generalize to other cases, in other words. I hope readers check them out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we directly apply the `data.frame` on the output, it wouldn't work because of the `class`

```
as.data.frame(kappam.fleiss(diagnoses2))
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(kappam.fleiss(diagnoses2)) :
> cannot coerce class ‘"irrlist"’ to a data.frame

We may convert to `data.frame` within `do.call`

```
out <- do.call(data.frame, kappam.fleiss(diagnoses2))
```

-check the structure

```
> str(out)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ method   : chr "Fleiss' Kappa for m Raters"
 $ subjects : int 30
 $ raters   : int 3
 $ irr.name : chr "Kappa"
 $ value    : num 0.534
 $ stat.name: chr "z"
 $ statistic: num 9.89
 $ p.value  : num 0
```

Once we convert to `data.frame`, the `kable` will work

```
> knitr::kable(out, "latex")

\begin{tabular}{l|r|r|l|r|l|r|r}
\hline
method & subjects & raters & irr.name & value & stat.name & statistic & p.value\\
\hline
Fleiss' Kappa for m Raters & 30 & 3 & Kappa & 0.5343368 & z & 9.893792 & 0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this out in about 15 minutes and I'll mark the answer if it works or give you another comment if it doesn't. Thanks as always Akrun.

Comment: Works very well, cheers. Though check out @TarJae answer above with GTSummary, also very clean!

Answer (score 2):

We could use `gtsummary`. See here for detailed adaptions: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/

```
out <- do.call(data.frame, kappam.fleiss(diagnoses2))

library(gtsummary)

out %>% 
  tbl_summary
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, didn't know about `gtsummary`. Looks brilliant. I'll check out the documentation when I have some time later, but it looks like the output is images, right -- PDF or PNG or so?

Comment: It is really worth it to take some minutes to go through ´gtsummary` IT produces really publication ready tables!